# Interop Word Add Shape Giving Exeption - Public member 'Shapes' on type 'ApplicationClass' not found

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

I am adding image to word file and I found one solution. When I implemented that solution to my code. I is giving System.MissingMemberException: Public member 'Shares' on type 'ApplicationClass' not found.

```
    Dim autoScaledInlineShape As InlineShape = wordApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strImageFileName)
    Dim scaledWidth As Single = autoScaledInlineShape.Width
    Dim scaledHeight As Single = autoScaledInlineShape.Height
    autoScaledInlineShape.Delete()
    Dim newShape As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape = wordApp.Shapes.AddShape(1, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight)
    newShape.Fill.UserPicture(strImageFileName)
    Dim finalInlineShape As InlineShape = newShape.ConvertToInlineShape()
    finalInlineShape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
    finalInlineShape.Range.Cut()
    wordApp.Selection.Paste()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Shapes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.shapes) property belongs to the `Document` class, not Word `Application`.

```
Dim autoScaledInlineShape As InlineShape = wordApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strImageFileName)
    Dim scaledWidth As Single = autoScaledInlineShape.Width
    Dim scaledHeight As Single = autoScaledInlineShape.Height
    autoScaledInlineShape.Delete()
    Dim newShape As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(1, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight)
    newShape.Fill.UserPicture(strImageFileName)
    Dim finalInlineShape As InlineShape = newShape.ConvertToInlineShape()
    finalInlineShape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
    finalInlineShape.Range.Cut()
    wordApp.Selection.Paste()
```